# Can not create local user account that allows login anymore

Tags: authentication, windows-10

I am trying to create some local user accounts in Windows 10 on my home PC.  I can go through the wizard ok, but when I try to login to the accounts I get a message similar to 'user profile service failed the logon'.

The whole story is this:
I want to add a SSD drive to my system (Dell Tower, I do not remember the model). So following some advice, it was suggested to move my user files to another drive so the SSD drive would only have the OS and programs on it. Plus this would keep my SSD required size smaller.

So I started to move my user files using the "Location" tab for the "My Documents" and similar folders to my other drive.  This all appeared to work okay.

I then selected my wife's folders but I could not since I was not logged under her account, fine. I logged out of my account and attempted to log into her account (we both have administrator rights). That is when I received the 'user profile failed' message.

I have third account on the system, another admin account, and it too failed. Windows seems to be accepting the passwords, just failing further into the login process.

I logged back into my account and my desktop is completely different, there are only 3 icons there now instead of the ~20 I had before, so something with the 'move' failed? I'm not sure.   I moved the files back to the default location and that did not help. I googled the 'user profile service failed' message and it seems this happens often enough that there are fairly detailed instructions about how to fix it.

The one fix was to examine the registry (this was from support.mircosoft.com) HLM\Software\Microsoft\windows nt\CurrentVersion\ProfileList and 'simply' remove the '.bak' suffix from entries that match the accounts that are broke.  Set some other values to 0. In my case the values were not present in the values list.

I did this and it did not help. I did reboots at various times throughout this process, but those did not help either....

So I tried to create a new account(s), but no matter how I created the account I could never log into the account.  Right now, I have only one account that I can log into.

I have not tried the "net user" command as I have just found some information about here at work.  I did have to use that program to reset my account's password recently.  I have used the same password at home for years, so I do not know how it changed. Luckily, my wife's account still worked at that time and it was an administrator account. So maybe that was some indication that the 'user subsystem' was failing in someway.

This PC is seldom connected to the Internet, only for Windows updates or downloading a program, like "Open Office", Paint.Net type of things.  We mainly use an older XP machine for computer work and a tablet for surfing the 'net.  The computer is 'new' to us and we have not migrated our files to it.  In fact the PC is seldom used at all and powered off for months at a time.  I am pretty much the only person that even uses the system, my wife went through a "Dummy's for Windows 10" book and decided it was too different to really bother with learning a whole new thing.

I will try 'net user' tonight to add another account and see if that helps.

Thanks for any hints or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's happened, but it looks like the accounts are probably corrupted. You can do it, but Windows much prefers to have the user profiles on the same drive as the installation itself. **Moving** them entirely may be the cause of the issue.

(For future reference, If you want to copy user accounts across to a new SSD, it's always best to start here: C:\Users\xxxxx). xxx being your userID. If you would like to use it as your primary C:Drive for Windows - I would advise just a clean install.

You could try a couple of things at this point. (Make sure you're connected to the internet if you can)

1. First, try just making sure your connected to the internet and run all the updates you can. The profile service may just be corrupted and Win10 especially might just need an internet connection to sort it automatically.
2. Try booting into [recovery mode](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10), and run a system restore back a few days. The files may not return but it *might* fix the profile issues.
3. If you can still login to your wifes profile, [use this tool](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) (after backing up your files) to clear out all the old profiles.

Net user will likely just enable the hidden admin account, and would not be all that useful if your wife's account is already and administrator.

Comment: Weird that the other accounts that I did *not* move became corrupted. The only account I *can* log in to is the one I did the relocations to. Still do not understand why adding *new* accounts did not work at all. The 'net user newuser password /ADD' command did not create a usable account either. If i just type 'net user' it lists all the accounts, so part of the system knows that are there. I do not have a Windows10 install disk; the PC was a BestBuy 'Demo' PC on sale and came with very little extra.